# can people view amount of whois requests?

Tags: domain-name, whois

I went on who.is to find a domain name to buy. It was currently in use, so I waited till it expired, but as soon as it had a domain name parker went and sat on it.

Is it possible for people to see how many whois requests have been made to this site. I want to know if they saw me looking at it and then took it because they saw someone interested in it so they could scam me.

The domain name is a very unpolular one, it doesnt seem to have ever had any visitors so I don't know how they found it otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why a domain gets picked up right after expiration. Somebody could have already put a request to buy it. Here's a resource to get you stated on getting domains after they expire.

For what it's worth, I don't believe your situation had anything to do with you having searched for the domain before.

http://www.pixelmade.com/blog/domain-names/how-buy-expired-domain-name

Comment: Thanks. That is really helpful. I used a back-order hoping that I could get it, but it says here there are many times to get it before it gets to a back order.